# Hash функция и таблицы (C++)

Tags: c++, хеширование

Нужно написать хэш-функцию hash на C++, которая для key типа string будет возвращать возможный индекс:

```
h(key, m) = h(key, n, m)

if i = 0:  h(key, i, m) = 0   
else:      h(key, i, m) = (256 * h(key, i - 1, m) + key_i) % m)

n - длина key
```

Mетод initHashList, который создает и инициализирует массив типа HashEntry и выдает указатель на этот массив. При инициализации задает значения: key - пустая строка, value - (-1), used - false.

```
struct HashEntry{

std::string key;    //the key of the entry
bool used;          //the value of the entry
int value;          //marks if the entry was used before

};
```

Ну и на последок метод insert, который добавляет запись в хэш-лист(принимает key, value)

Comment: В с++ элементарно есть уже готовый класс для создания хэша.

Comment: Если это реальная задача, не стройте велосипед и воспользуйтесь [`std::unordered_set<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). Если это учебная задача, решайте её сами, иначе вы ничему не научитесь.

Comment: Именно поэтому мне нужна подсказка, а не ответ.